# Ways to concat test results from each of the bazel tests?

Tags: linux, azure, azure-devops, bazel, bazel-extra-action

I have a build file that runs some Bazel tests , like this on Azure pipeline

```
jobs:
  - job: "results_extraction"
    timeoutInMinutes: 720

    steps:
      - bash: |
          ./install_conda_environment.sh update
        displayName: "Update conda env"

      - bash: |
          source ${HOME}/.bashrc
          bazel test test1
          --test_output=all
          --test_summary=detailed
        continueOnError: true
        displayName: "Run test1"

      - bash: |
          source ${HOME}/.bashrc
          bazel test test2
          --test_output=all
          --test_summary=detailed
        continueOnError: true
        displayName: "Run test2"

     - task: PublishTestResults@2
          condition: succeededOrFailed()
          inputs:
            testResultsFiles: 'bazel-testlogs/**/*.xml'
            testRunTitle: 'Publish test results.'
          displayName: 'Bazel Tests Publish Results'
```

But when I go to the bazel-test directory , I cannot find these tests (I looked for test.xml). My guess is bazel sandboxing deletes it but I could be wrong.
All I want to do is extract the results of each of these test indiviudal tests. Is there a flag in bazel that allows me to do create a detailed test result containing status of each test?

Comment: Hi Does Brian's answer help? Please check it and kindly let us know the result.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your tests to write the files to [`$TEST_UNDECLARED_OUTPUTS_DIR`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/test-encyclopedia.html#test-interaction-with-the-filesystem) (an environment variable which bazel sets when running tests), the files will be saved at `bazel-testlogs/<package>/<target>/test.outputs/outputs.zip`. Then, you can write something to gather those up and process them.